# How to combine 'where-clauses' with Dates

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have to get the number of users who viewed at least one video in a given day and the number of the users who returned the next day to view at least one video from the following table. I've been able to get the count by using the Count statement but for some reason is only showing the first date? The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(user_id) from clickstream_videos WHERE event_name = 'video_play'
```

[image]

UPDATE ---

I was able to get the following query to work in Microsoft SQL Server, any suggestions on getting this to work on myphp?

```
WITH uservideoviewvideo (date, (user_id) AS 
    (SELECT  DISTINCT date, user_id 
    FROM clickstream_videos
    WHERE event_name ='video_play' and user_id IS NOT NULL) 
SELECT currentday.date AS date, COUNT(currentday.user_id) AS users_view_videos, COUNT(nextday.user_id) AS users_view_next_day
FROM userviewvideo currentday
LEFT JOIN userviewvideo nextday ON currentday.user_id = nextday.user_id AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, currentday.date) = nextday.date
GROUP BY currentday.date
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between the same user watching multiple videos? Should the same user be counted twice, or only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `lag()` and `group by`:

```
select cv.date, count(distinct user_id) as users_on_day,
       count(distinct case when prev_date = date - interval '1 day' then user_id end) as returning_users
from (select cv.*, lag(date) over (partition by user_id) as prev_date
      from clickstream_videos cv
      where event_name = 'video_play'
     ) cv
group by cv.date;
```

Note that date functions are highly database dependent.  So the exact syntax for comparing dates might differ in your database.